# Jquery with dynamic content in angular-formly

Tags: jquery, angular-formly

I have a field

```
{
        key: 'last',
        type: 'input',
        model: vm.model.name,
        className: 'flex flex-gt-xs-100 left-element',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Last Name'
        }
      }
```

I need using Jquery to hide it, not hideExpression
When I use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.left-element').hide();
});
```

It doesn't work.
But when it binded event:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('body').click(function(){
            $('.left-element').hide();
     }
 });
```

It works.
What happens? I want to hide element when enter page, not after clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You have constructed it to set class on click. You must set it on page load. Sometging like this:

```
 `window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('.left-        elemnt').hide();
 };`
```

Or if you're using jQuery:

```
 `$(function() {
  $('.left-element').hide();
  });`

  `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#left-elemnt').hide();
  });`
```